# scraping javascript data with simple_html_dom.php

Tags: php, regex, external

i just get this string as result from scrap a script tag from external page with simple_html_dom.php

```
var secs = 0; 
var lastp = 0;
var newInstance = newObjce("xxx").setup(    
"more":[{.....}], 
"sources": [
{"file":"url1","label":"360p","default":"true"},
{"file":"url2","label":"480p"},
{"file":"url3","label":"720p"},
{"file":"url4","label":"1080p HD"}
], 
"morestuff":[{......}])
```

how can get the data between "sources"[ ..this data...] and asign in php variable? 
making var_dump to this always returning string object
using json_encode dont work for me because after apply and make var_dump return always string object, this is why i think regexp can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a solution, i discovery this page to generate regexp online
http://txt2re.com/index-php.php3, leave here the function to solve my question, if anybody need this in the future

```
$re1='.*?'; # Non-greedy match on filler
$re2='("sources".*?\\[.*?\\])'; # Double Quote String 1
if ($c=preg_match_all ("/".$re1.$re2."/is", $string, $matches))
{
  $string1=$matches[1][0];
  print ($string1);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking to get done *can* be done with regex, but it may not be the best option. For example, you can match between the first bracket "[" after `sources` and the stop matching after the next close bracket after the opening one. See https://regex101.com/r/mVVEGp/1.

However, you're risking having trouble if there is ever a close bracket before you'd expect it (eg. inside a string). You may be better off just parsing the JSON using a proper parser. json_decode is a well established native PHP implementation. There are other implementations that allow reading JSON as a stream, which would work well for large sets of data.

The short of it is regex is likely not the best option in this use case.

Comment: thanks, i was tryng make this task with json_decode, but the data from simple_html_dom is pulling is string, i cant make work json_encode on this string, because json_string putme a lot of data onthis way  array([0]=>(all code i need search is nested here),[1]=>(more innecesary code here));  if you have a good example of how can making work with json_decode i really give you a big thanks

Comment: Re-reading the example, it's probably not JSON (just Javascript, there is a difference). I updated the regex to look for the first closing bracket "]" at the very beginning of a line after the first opening bracket. https://regex101.com/r/mVVEGp/2. This may get you closer to where you need to go. Note the flags "gsm". There is no good solution to your question without a proper parser.